# Bridge unable to connect to rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, bridge

I have rabbitmq running...

> $ rabbitmq-server   Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...   6 plugins
>   activated:
>   * amqp_client-0.0.0
>   * mochiweb-1.3-rmq0.0.0-git
>   * rabbitmq_management-0.0.0
>   * rabbitmq_management_agent-0.0.0
>   * rabbitmq_mochiweb-0.0.0
>   * webmachine-1.7.0-rmq0.0.0-hg      node with name "rabbit" already running on "barber"

When I try to run `~/.bridge/server start` it shuts down with crash report. Nothing in the documentation talks about configuring rabbitmq.

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 11-Jul-2012::08:29:10 ===  
    trap_exit: false  
  crasher:  
    status: running  
    initial call: gateway_gamqp:init/1  
    heap_size: 377  
    pid: <0.927.0>  
    stack_size: 24  
    registered_name: []  
    reductions: 316  
    exception exit: cannot_connect_to_rabbit  
  neighbours:  
      in function  gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 328)  
    ancestors: [gateway_app_sup,<0.921.0>]  
    messages: []  
    links: [<0.923.0>]  
    dictionary: []  
    trap_exit: false  
    status: running  
    heap_size: 377  
    stack_size: 24  
    reductions: 316
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the connection with *python* here? Please consider using appropriate tags.

Comment: Trying to getbridge in conjunction with python servers, clients  (bridgepython)

Comment: Is RabbitMQ configured to run on a custom port?

Comment: port 5672... think thats default rabbitmq port

Answer (score 0):

Try running it without rabbitmq also possibly sudo ~/.bridge/server start